# wget chose location ftp download

Tags: authentication, download, ftp, directory, wget

im trying to use wget for FTP download ( auth ) 
this is the command i used to download the file bat.bat in appdata dir ... 
i got my file inside new folder created by wget named ( website.com )

> wget -r --ftp-user="user" --ftp-password="pass" ftp://website.com/bat.bat -P %appdata%

when i checked appdata directory i found my file here :

C:\Users\ev\AppData\Roaming\website.com\bat.bat

i dont need it to create new dir i need it here :

C:\Users\ev\AppData\Roaming\bat.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `-nH` parameter:

```
wget -r -nH --ftp-user="user" --ftp-password="pass" ftp://website.com/bat.bat -P %appdata%
```

From wget --help:

```
Directories:
  -nd, --no-directories           don't create directories.
  -x,  --force-directories        force creation of directories.
  -nH, --no-host-directories      don't create host directories.
       --protocol-directories     use protocol name in directories.
  -P,  --directory-prefix=PREFIX  save files to PREFIX/...
       --cut-dirs=NUMBER          ignore NUMBER remote directory components.
```